# How to handle the deleted tweets in AMP pages

Tags: c#, amp-html

I have AMP pages that implements the amp-twitter" and I add the div fallback in it, to handle the cases when the tweets is deleted,
but the problem is when the tweet is deleted, the fallback div appears with large empty space below it,

how can I remove this empty space and just display an error message, or just hide the tweet area when the tweet is deleted?

Comment: the specified layout 'CONTAINER' is not supported by tag 'amp-twitter'.

Comment: The attribute 'layout' may not appear in tag 'div'.

Comment: How can I add layout attribute to the parent of amp-twitter tag, while this attribute is just for amp tags